# sIFR 3 - Selector

Tags: html, css, sifr, selector

I'm using [sIFR 3](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/) (beta revision 436).

I have a simple question, but I can't figure out the solution. I want to select an `<a>`-tag directly by it's class, not by its parent like I'm doing now:

```
sIFR.replace(din, {
   selector: '.mainmenu'
   ,css: [
     '.sIFR-root { font-size:13px; text-transform:uppercase; cursor:pointer; text-align:center }'
     ,'a { text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF; }'
     ,'a:link { color: #FFFFFF; }'
     ,'a:hover { color: #CCCCCC;}'
   ]
   ,transparent: true
  }
);
```

`".mainmenu"` is the class of a `<span>` containing the `<a>`. But sometimes a can't use this method and need the call the `<a>`-tag directly. All the examples I found on the internet seems to use the method above.

Can anyone help me how to write my selector?

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace `<a>` directly, you *must* replace a parent element for links to work cross-browser. But of course you use different CSS selectors to get at a parent element.